# Trying to use portsnap to install vim in FreeNAS

Tags: vim, freebsd, freenas

I am trying to install vim in FreeNAS but when I try to use `portsnap`, I get "command not found".

When I tried using 
pck_add -r portmaster I get the following:

```
 pkg_add -r portmaster

Error: Unable to get ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9-stable/Latest/portmaster.tbz: File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)
pkg_add: unable to fetch 'ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9-stable/Latest/portmaster.tbz' by URL
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be reading some very old doc, `pkg_add` has been gone from FreeBSD for quite a while. Instead, use `pkg`. And, we have good binary packages now, so there's no need install `portmaster` and then compile from source. Instead, just install vim directly by doing `pkg install vim` or if you prefer not to have the X11 version, `pkg install vim-lite`.

Comment: Here is the output from pkg install vim: [root@freenas] ~# pkg install vim
The package management tool is not yet installed on your system.
The mechanism for doing this is not secure on FreeBSD 9.2. To securely install
pkg(8), use ports from a portsnap checkout:
  # portsnap fetch extract
  # make -C /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg install clean
Do you still want to fetch and install it now? [y/N]: y
Bootstrapping pkg please wait
_http._tcp.pkg.FreeBSD.org
pkg: fail to extract pkg-static

Comment: 9.2 is no longer supported, you should upgrade to at least 9.3.

Comment: Also, I notice it looks like you're running FreeNAS. FreeNAS is great and is based on FreeBSD but it is not FreeBSD. Please tag your question as FreeNAS.

Comment: When I type uname it shows "FreeBSD"

Comment: True and it is based on FreeBSD, but they do their own releases and change things quite a bit so it's at least fair to warn potential readers of your question of what you are actually using so that they can help you better. I don't keep up with FreeNAS so I'm not sure if they've removed `pkg_add` yet or not. My answer is correct for FreeBSD but may or may not be correct for FreeNAS.